# Accessing the parent context of a web component being either DOM or Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

Context:

I am carrying out tests about web component composition in different contexts. Particularly I am trying to relate several web component by getting access to one of them from another one by a searching process within the `DOM` / `Shadow DOM` of the involved components.

Problem:

Let's suppose we have a web component named `x-foo` requiring to access another one `x-randgen`. The latter component exposes business methods used by the former. In order to avoid a tightly coupled communication between both components I would like to use a discovery mechanism in `x-foo` to access `x-randgen` through a searching process across `DOM` and `Shadow DOM` models. In particular I identify two possible scenarios. Either both `x-foo` and `x-randgen` instantiated are in the global context (index.html) or they both appear within another template, say `x-bar`. The problem is that the searching process should be implemented differently in each case. Following I show a pseudocode with my approach summarizing, in essence, my question. (The global example can be found here: http://jsbin.com/qokif/1/)

```
    Polymer('x-foo', {
       ...
       getRandGen: function () {
          if (<<x-foo & x-randgen are in the global context>>)
             return document.querySelector('x-randgen');
          else if (<<x-foo & x-randgen are in a template>>)
             return <<the x-randgen tag within the template>>;
       }
    });
```

Question:

I would appreciate if someone could reformulate the snippet above in proper terms according to the Polymer technology.

Comment: Have you considered having the code that uses these two elements hooking them up to one another? Something like `<x-foo id='foo' randgen='{{$.randgen}}'>` `<x-randgen id='randgen' foo='{{$.foo}}'>`. It's generally better to be explicit about this sort of thing when possible.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I am researching about different composition models within the web components landscape. The solution that you are proposing fits in well with direct communication and I have successfully tested it but I consider that loosely coupled communication  is appropriated for other situations. In general terms I think it would be a useful tool to have a method to access the parent context be it the global one or a template. In fact, in my opinion, the code for accessing the parent context should not depend of the context where the wc instance lives.

Comment: The reason I'd push for an explicit binding is that it's nice to have a way to correct it or override it when it gets things wrong. e.g. if there are multiple `x-randgen` elements, or you want to use a different element depending on circumstances. In any case, enough abstract worrying, I think I've spotted why this isn't working for you.

Comment: IMO, both loose and explicit communication are valuable. You can mostly have your cake and eat it too using the monostate and/or controller techniques described below. E.g. the controller can do easy-to-understand explicit coordination between elements, while the individual elements can simply ask questions without knowing where the answers come from. More extreme loose coupling can be done with `polymer-signals` (soon to be `core-signals`), which is a generic pub-sub system, but this should be used extremely sparingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write your problem function like this:

```
    getRandGen: function () {
      var root = this;
      while (root.parentNode) {
        root = root.parentNode;
      }
      return root.querySelector('x-randgen');
    }
```

http://jsbin.com/xufewi/1/edit

Other solutions can be made using monostate pattern (rare) or a proper controller (common).

The monostate idea is that a particular element expresses a conduit to a shared-state (i.e. the `max` value). Wherever you need access to the shared-state, you simply create one of the accessor elements.

The controller idea is that the element bubbles an event requesting the `randgen` utility. Some ancestor (the controller) handles the event and provides the resource. This is a type of dependency management that's great for design flexibility.

http://jsbin.com/tudow/1/edit

Comment: Fwiw, also notice that you don't need to scrape `max` property from attributes. This happens automatically.

Comment: +1 for the idea of using event bubbling, that's really elegant

Comment: Glad that helped. Fwiw, it can be hard to define _first_ using this searching approach; this is why we prefer the bubble-to-controller technique: the first eligible _controller_ is easier to reason about.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. Your while-based searching answers properly what I was questioning. Though in my scenario it is required that `getRandGen` returns the nearest `<x-randgen>` tag within the scope chain according to the closest nested scope rule typical in compiler theory. Anyway your cue is enough for me to develop the method properly.

Comment: In relation to your other solutions they seem very interesting and in fact I had already considered them. Nevertheless what I needed was the solution for exactly the question I posted. This is because I am not trying to solve a specific problem but identifying canonical scenarios where different coordination models are applied. Within my conceptual framework your solutions belong to other categories already covered on my research. Maybe when I have finished my work I could share it to get your appreciated feedback.

Comment: I understand, this is why I led with an answer to your direct question before the digression. Sometimes when Architecture A is examined by Pattern B, false negatives can result when A and B are not well matched; this is a general problem I try steer around. However, in this case, you seem to have a sound methodology. I'm definitely interested in your research, thanks for offering to share the results!

Comment: Thank you very much for such a kind comment ;). I would appreciate if you could take a glance at a similar searching problem involving insertion points (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060397)

Answer (score 1):

Two bugs in your jsbin. The first is that you want `domReady`, not `ready` because you call `getRandGen()` inside, which queries the DOM. Even that is a bit brittle though because it depends on the `x-randgen` element existing at the time that your `x-foo`'s domReady event fires (so it wouldn't work if `x-randgen` is in a conditional template e.g.

The second issue is that `document.querySelector('x-randgen')` won't find an `<x-randgen>` inside of a ShadowDOM.

A bit of terminology clarification here. The "template context" and "global context" ideas aren't quite right.  Polymer elements instantiate their `<template>`s inside of their shadow roots, which establish a shadow dom. The shadow dom is an abstraction for isolating components, so that they're less likely to interfere with the rest of the page, and the page is less likely to interfere with them. It is possible to reach across the shadow dom boundary, but just be aware that you may be reaching into the implementation details of other components.

All that to say that if you don't care what `x-randgen` you get a hold of, even if it's within some totally unrelated component, this should work: `document.querySelector('x-randgen') || document.querySelector('body /deep/ x-randgen')`. JSBin: http://jsbin.com/goqikire/1/edit

Ideally though you'd have a better idea of where the `x-randgen` will be relative to your `x-foo`, or as I suggested above the component responsible for both the `x-randgen` and the `x-foo` can explicitly make them aware of each other.

Comment: Thanks for your bug report Peter. I take note of them. IMO the sync-related issues are the trickiest problems with components. In relation to your terminology clarification I totally agree with you and I was already aware of it. Maybe my way of expressing it was not totally adequate. Finally, I cannot grasp your solution (`/deep/` is unknown for me) but in fact it does not work. Note that my aim is that one `<x-foo>` uses `<x-randgen>`with `max=10` whilst the other uses that with `max=20` and your code always gets the one with 10. Please see the scope discussion in my comment to Scott.